# How to resolve text alignment issue in AntD form

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have an AntD Modal which has a Form that I'm struggling to align some text on. Here is what it looks like with the text highlighted in yellow. I would like it to be aligned with the first column where I've drawn the red box.

[image]

The section of code that contains the "personal information" text and the applicant form fields looks like this:

```
  <Form
    ref={this.formRef}
    {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
    onFinish={onFinish}
    id="myForm"
    validateMessages={validateMessages}
    initialValues={{ applicants: [{ firstName: '' }] }}
  >
    {
      <Form.List name="applicants">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Form.Item {...formItemLayout}}>
                <Row>
                  <Col span={24}>
                    Personal Information
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Form.Item>
              {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <Form.Item {...formItemLayout} label={`Applicant #${index + 1}`} key={field.key}>
                  <Row key={field.key} gutter={[0, 8]} justify="start">
                    <Col span={12}>
                      <Row gutter={[4, 4]}>
                        <Col span={7}>
                          <Form.Item name={[field.name, 'firstName']} fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'firstName']} rules={rules}>
                            <Input placeholder="First Name" ref={this.inputRef} />
                          </Form.Item>
                        </Col>
```

I thought perhaps if I set the label to a blank space it'd accomplish what I want on the form item and it does, but of course, the colon remains which I don't want. So I'm guessing this is not the right way to accomplish this and perhaps there's a better CSS route to go or something.

[image]

I'm looking for help on how to get the alignment that I want. Ultimately I'd also like to put "Employer Information" aligned with the right column over the employer information as well.

EDIT #1

Adding a simplified codesandbox of this problem here. Appreciate any ideas!

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-text-alignment-problem-ruexw?file=/src/MyForm.js)

Comment: I can help if you can reproduce a demo using this: https://codesandbox.io/s/

Comment: Added a codesandbox demonstrating what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for `Form.Item` to display the colon behind the `label`. You can check it out [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Item)

Disable it would accomplish what you want

```
<Form.Item {...formItemLayout} label=" " colon={false}>
  <Row gutter={[0, 8]} justify="start">
    <Col span={12}>Personal Information</Col>
    <Col span={12}>Employer Information</Col>
  </Row>
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add labelCol and wrapperCol like below:

```
  <Form
    layout="horizontal"
    labelCol={{
      span: 6
    }}
    wrapperCol={{
      span: 18
    }}
    labelAlign="right"
  >
   ...
  </Form>
```